# How to add a new attribute in menu item in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.4

I want to add a new attribute "rel" in a menu item in joomla. To add display a modal box on click of menu item I need to add "re" attribute. 
for e.g. 
at present the menu item is - `<a href="#" class="someclass"> ... </a>`
I want - `<a href="#" class="someclass" rel"something"> ... </a>`

After a research I found that updating a file - /modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_url.php should help. But when I am trying to update this  file it does not reflect any changes on joomla backend.

Can anyone please suggest what should be the possible solution?

TIA

Comment: are you trying to add "rel" attributes to admin menus or in backend?

Comment: If you are trying to override the backend menu make sure you are working with the backend (administrator) model. Also do not modify the file, override it by making a copy in your html folder.  (lots of answers on SO about how to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, your file **"/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default_url.php"** is for site/frontend menu, not for the administrator/backend menu.

However, regardless of frontend and backend, if you want to modify any view of joomla's components or modules or layouts, then you must override it in your template's html folder.

In your scenario, your file should reside in **"/templates/mytemplate/html/mod_menu/default_url.php"**